# Is there any iTunesConnect API to get all transactions of particular day or month of itunes account for all the customers?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-sdk, itunes-app

Is there any iTunesConnect API to get all transactions of particular day or month of itunes account for all the customers?

We need to get list of all transactions (all payment received in our itunes account for particular day or month?

We just need to API information which help us to get all transactions from iTunes account. All payment received in itunes account.